# How change TextView text

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
                 DateTime startDate8 = DateTime.now(); 
                 DateTime endDate8 = new DateTime(2014, 11, 5, 15, 0);

                 Period period8 = new Period(startDate8, endDate8, PeriodType.dayTime());

                 PeriodFormatter formatter8 = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                 .appendMinutes()
                 .toFormatter(); 

               tw.setText(String.valueOf(formatter8.print(period8)));
```

My android app.

```
if tw is empty;
tw="00"

if tw is one-digit text, one-digit value = "x";
tw = "0x"
```

tw is text in TextView. i want write "00" to tw when tw was empty
i want write prefix "0" to tw when tw was one-digit character

i explained https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbIT1.png

Comment: And we want you to show your attempts. Did you search through the android doc? If yes which methods did you find to help you with this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(tws.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
tw.setText("00")
}

if(tws.getText().toString().equals("x")){
tw.setText("0x")
}
```

Comment: good code but one-digit value isnt x. one-digit value can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: I would use String.format("%02d", num) instead of a condition

Comment: i should count digit in tw

Comment: What do you mean with you should count digits in tw? tw is a TextView, whenever you set the text, it gets converted to a String anyway.

Comment: thanks, i completed my code but app has stopped unfortunately